# Python input with multiple items/requests

Tags: python, string, list, input

I'm new to coding in Python and I am stuck on the following:

I have a list of items as inputs, which is seperated by empty newlines, like so:

```
input = """Andrew
Bob
Chanel
Danielle

Andrew Chanel 1 0
Danielle Bob 0 1

Andrew Danielle 0.5 0.5
Chanel Bob 1 0

Andrew Bob 0.5 0.5
Chanel Danielle"""
```

In this input, the first 4 lines should be the seen as the names of all players in a classed called `result` with a string called name. After the first empty newline, however, it gives the names of the two players followed by their result (1 = win, 0 = loss, both 0.5 = tie). Every newline is a new battle, and until a new **empty** newline is one round.

My question: what are the steps that I need to specify that:

1. the first part before an empty newline is all players involved?
2. the 'paragraphs' afterwards are rounds?
3. that the first name is 'player_1', the second name 'player_2', the first value 'score_player_1' and the second value 'score_player_2'?

If anyone would be so kind to help a beginner out, I' appreciate it!

Comment: If this format is fixed, you can first split on 2 newlines `s.split("\n\n")` to get the separate blocks,  and then use split again to get the individual parts.

Comment: Did you try anything at all? Some kind of research? Are you aware of [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)? What about [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```py
x = """Andrew
Bob
Chanel
Danielle

Andrew Chanel 1 0
Danielle Bob 0 1

Andrew Danielle 0.5 0.5
Chanel Bob 1 0

Andrew Bob 0.5 0.5
Chanel Danielle 0 1"""


_names, *rounds = x.split('\n\n')
names = _names.splitlines() # ['Andrew', 'Bob', 'Chanel', 'Danielle']


for _round in rounds:
    print('NEW ROUND')
    for match in _round.splitlines():
        # Use these variables:
        name1, name2, score1, score2 = match.split()
        print('MATCH:', name1, 'vs', name2, '| SCORE:', score1, '-', score2)
    print('')
```

Output:

```
NEW ROUND
MATCH: Andrew vs Chanel | SCORE: 1 - 0
MATCH: Danielle vs Bob | SCORE: 0 - 1

NEW ROUND
MATCH: Andrew vs Danielle | SCORE: 0.5 - 0.5
MATCH: Chanel vs Bob | SCORE: 1 - 0

NEW ROUND
MATCH: Andrew vs Bob | SCORE: 0.5 - 0.5
MATCH: Chanel vs Danielle | SCORE: 0 - 1
```